# Expected Values for Nonquantitative Outcomes

Tags: probability, expected-value

For a 3-sided die $(1, 2, 3)$ and random variable $X$ for outcomes, the expected value $E(X)$ is such that $$E(X)=\frac{1}{3}\times 1 + \frac{1}{3}\times 2 + \frac{1}{3}\times 3$$ This is ok.

But when the outcomes are *not* quantities I have a problem e.g. for a coin toss we have heads and tails. How do I calculate the expected value in this case? If $X$ is the random variable representing the outcomes of coin toss then $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}\times ?? + \frac{1}{2}\times ??$

Gracias in advance.

Comment: Typically you count the number of heads or the number of tails.

Comment: Can I *quantify* the *qualities* e.g. Heads = 1 and Tails = 2. The result is that $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}\times 1 + \frac{1}{2}\times 2 = 1.5$???

Comment: what you do is to assign a function value from the "event space" $\Omega$ to the reals. For example, for heads or tails, we can say that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $X(\text{heads})=1$, $X(\text{tails})=0$. With this function, we are actually counting "the amount of times that the coin lands in a head", with assigned value of 1 per event that results in heads (effectively counting the amount of times), and 0 for tails (i.e. not counting this). We can construct such event-to-number representation anytime we like, and hence we can always study probabilities in the sense of random variables

Comment: @cjferes, that checks out. I see no issues. Do you have anything more to add?

Comment: Not really, that is basically the setup to "translate" events to random variables. Of course it can be more formal, but I assumed you aimed for a more intuitive answer.